# Let $A\in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$, $P_A(x)=\prod_{j=1}^{k} (x - \lambda_j)^{n_j}$, and $g\in \mathbb{C}[X]$. Find a C.P. for $g(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, jordan-normal-form

Let $A\in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$.
Its characteristic polynomial $P_A(x)=\prod_{j=1}^{k} (x - \lambda_j)^{n_j}$,
and $g\in \mathbb{C}[X]$.
Find a characteristic polynomial for $g(A)$.

I believe that the solution has something to do with Jordan forms, but haven't figured out how I should be approaching it.

Comment: It's not restrictive to assume $A$ is in Jordan normal form, so also $g(A)$ is a block diagonal matrix (although not generally in Jordan form). Since the characteristic polynomial of a block diagonal matrix is the product of the characteristic polynomials of its blocks, you can reduce the problem to finding the characteristic polynomial of $g(B)$, where $B$ is a Jordan block.

Comment: May I ask why is it not restrictive to assume that $A$ is in Jordan normal form?

Comment: Because if $A=SJS^{-1}$ then $g(A)=Sg(J)S^{-1}$ and similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial

Comment: That is actually a pretty clever idea, thanks!
But how do I know for sure that a Jordan form exists for any given matrix A?

Comment: A Jordan form exists for every matrix whose characteristic polynomial splits into linear factors.